# My text is not aligned, what is causing this?

Tags: fonts, align

I noticed recently that across all my files, each line is slightly misaligned.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, depending on the line number, the text is off a bit.
I tried changing fonts with no luck.

Which setting is causing this?

Some of my settings:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Jetbrains Mono" :height 150)

(column-number-mode)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1) ;; line numbers globally
```

Comment: BTW, in the second image it looks as if the line wrapped. It's not clear to me that that's evidence of misalignment. Am I missing something?

Comment: Even if there is line wrap, doesnt the line start after the numbers on the left? Nether the less, the first image does show misalignment.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should have a fringe indicator too which I don't see.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly using a proportional font, rather than a monospaced font. Use `C-u C-x =` to view the details for any character in the buffer. You will see there the actual font used to render that character. Perhaps “Jetbrains Mono” wasn’t available?

Comment: Also, when i try to load a font that is not available, I get an error in the mini buffer. Jetbrains Mono is the font being used in that image.

Comment: Result from `C-u Cx =` is =>  `mac-ct:-*-JetBrains Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`

Comment: Are you sure that’s the same font shown in your first screenshot? It’s clearly not monospaced.

Comment: mmm I could be wrong about that then. How can I confirm and fix it? the C-u C-x says its JetBrains Mono though, so what should I take from that?

Comment: Try Liberation Mono Regular or some other monospaced font. It may be a bug in JetBrains Mono.

Comment: It seems that, the issue is the font with the line numbers. No matter which mono spaced font i change it to the issue persists.

Comment: OK - do `M-x describe-face RET linum`, click on any `inherited` attribute too (if applicable) and add the result to your question.

Comment: NickD, you are my hero for this! I have been struggling with the answer to this for a while. Can you add this as an answer? (FYI - I did `M-x describe-face RET line-number`. Clicked on inherited, then changed the font there.)

Comment: Lucky guess :-) (and I even had the wrong face). Since you know the details and I don't, it might be better for you to supply an answer: it's bound to be more complete than what I could provide. In particular, what was the face that was inherited by the `line-number` face? What font  was it using and what did you change it to? Given those details, I could probably provide a reasonable answer, but it still might be better for you to do it.